# Ajax not displaying validation messages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have got a PHP contact form where I'm trying to implement Ajax to it to make it more user friendly because the contact form is a pop-up form using javascript/jQuery, so everytime the form is submitted it refreshes the page and you have to go back in the form to view the validation message.

Could you check what am I missing here please? I've been on it for sometime now and it still doesn't work. Please let me know if you want me to add the PHP script.

**Ajax code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function () {
            var str = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "demoform.php",
                data: str,

                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg == 'OK') {
                        result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
                        $("#fields").hide();
                    } else {
                        result = msg;
                    }

                    $("#note").html(result);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<center>
<p>Please complete the form below <br />to request a <br/> <span id="free_demo">FREE DEMO</span></p>

<div id="note"></div>
    <div id="fields">
<form id="ajax-contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="fullname" id="vpbfullname"     value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["fullname"]); ?>" class="vpb_input_fields">    <?php echo $submission_status1; ?></div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email"  id="email" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["email"]); ?>" class="vpb_input_fields"><?php echo $submission_status2; ?></div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Company" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["company"]); ?>" class="vpb_input_fields"><?php echo $submission_status3; ?></div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Telephone" name="phone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["phone"]); ?>" class="vpb_input_fields"><?php echo $submission_status4; ?></div>

<div class="vpb_captcha_wrappers"><input type="text" placeholder="Security  Code" id="vpb_captcha_code" name="vpb_captcha_code" class="vpb_input_fields">    </div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="refresh"  onClick="vpb_refresh_aptcha();">Refresh Security Code</a></font>
<br/><br/>
<div class="vpb_captcha_wrapper"><img src="vasplusCaptcha.php?rand=<?php   echo rand(); ?>"     id='captchaimg' ></div><br clear="all"><br/>

<br clear="all"> 

<div><?php echo $submission_status; ?></div><!-- Display success or error messages -->
<div>&nbsp;</div>

<input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="1">
<input type="submit" class="vpb_general_button"  value="Submit"></form>    </div>

<br clear="all">
</center>
```

Any help would be great.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preventDefault();`

```
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //....
};
```

This is preventing the form submit, but ajax call will happens.

Comment: Thank you it sends the e-mail out and the form works fine using Ajax. The only thing that doesn't work is the validation messages using Ajax

Comment: What do you mean not works? `$("#note").html(result);` should push the `msg` or the `div` into.  Try `console.log(msg);` in the else case when it fails. Are you sure you echoes something from `demoform.php`?

Comment: OMG!!! you nailed it... It Works!!!. I wasn't echoing anything on from the PHP form. How stupid of me.. thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to write onsubmit="return false" in your form tag like

Comment: <form id="ajax-contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false">

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you suggested and it still the validation messages are not displayed.

Comment: thanks Sunil but it's resolved now unless you still wants to view the PHP script? As suggested by '@lolka_bolka' the issue with the PHP script was that it wasn't echoing anything. Added echo to PHP and the validation works now. Thanks again for your time and support.